# S3 Event Notifications, Lambda Function, .NET SDK "Unable to validate the following destination configurations"

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, lambda

I have a scenario where I have to create the buckets dynamically, So after creating he bucket, I want to enable the Event Notification and I want to attach a Lambda Function to it. But I am having this error.
Here is my code for for Notifications:

[image]

Comment: The first suggestion by AWS: "Before subscribing an SNS topic to S3 event notifications, you must specify a topic policy AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy with the appropriate permissions and it must exist before the subscription occurs, otherwise it might fail." Did you verify it?

Comment: Thanks man, you were right!
before adding Lambda Function to S3 event notification, I have to give permission to specific lambda function first. After adding the permission, I enable event notification.

Comment: great. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/unable-validate-destination-s3/):

> Before subscribing an SNS topic to S3 event notifications, you must
>   specify a topic policy AWS::SNS::TopicPolicy with the appropriate
>   permissions and it must exist before the subscription occurs,
>   otherwise it might fail.